# Where can I found the configuration of my VNet with my Web-App on Azure?

Tags: azure, web-applications, vnet

The scenario in here is that I have created a WebApp which has Dynamic Outbound IPs, and we needed those IPs to get whitelisted on the DB side, Since there were too many IPs, we created a NAT Gateway, VNet and a single Public IP address through which we will communicate to the DB.
I need to know where lies the configuration for VNet with my Azure web app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist the public IP address to your firewall of DB because NAT provides source network address translation (SNAT) for a subnet.

> [NAT gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway-resource) resources specify which static IP addresses virtual
> machines use when creating outbound flows. Static IP addresses come
> from public IP address resources, public IP prefix resources, or both.
> If a public IP prefix resource is used, all IP addresses of the entire
> public IP prefix resource are consumed by a NAT gateway resource. A
> NAT gateway resource can use a total of up to 16 static IP addresses
> from either.

If you have enabled [web app with VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet), By default, BGP routes affect only your RFC1918 destination traffic. If `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` is set to `1`, all outbound traffic can be affected by your BGP routes.